# Garmin GPS SDK for a Garmin watch

Tags: garmin, connectiq

I am building an application for a running club.  We want to have everyone in the group buy the Forerunner and we want to send our longitude and latitude every 30-seconds to an API.  Is this possible?

I'm not sure if I can register a device in the database with a specific runner and then accept the coordinates in real time.

Answer (score 2):

Garmin just released an SDK for the new FR920xt watch, and probably other future devices. Perhaps that will be useful to you. http://developer.garmin.com/

Answer (score 0):

Not live.
Running Garmin Connect IQ apps will only be run in a "VM" on the watch, but you want use the phone connection in the CIQ, yet.